# Wireless not working since upgrading to Kubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu

I'm running Kubuntu 15.10 on a Dell Inspiron N7010
Never had any problems with wireless until the recent upgrade. 
The Connection Editor doesn't list any of the local connections as available.
Running `sudo lshw -class network` returns this

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:26:c7:e4:bb:12
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.2.0-18-generic firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 ip=192.168.1.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:28 memory:f0300000-f0301fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8152 v1.1 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: c1
       serial: f0:4d:a2:62:2d:5a
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.1-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:31 memory:f0200000-f023ffff ioport:3000(size=128)
```

I noticed that my wireless device has been renamed from wlan0 to wlp4s0. Running `sudo iw dev wlp4s0 scan` returns all the wireless networks available

For now, I can connect to a network by editing /etc/network/interfaces
At the moment it looks like this

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp5s0
iface enp5s0 inet dhcp

auto wlp4s0
iface wlp4s0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid myNetwork
        wpa-psk myPassword
```

but I have to edit this everytime to add a new connection.

If I click the refresh button in the network connections widget in the system tray I get the alert "Failed to request scan - Scanning not available while unavailable or scanning"

The results of the wireless info script are here: http://pastebin.com/wfYHvyhs

Comment: can anyone help with this issue?